# pipeline with PCA on feature subset only in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a set of features that I would like to model, one of which is actually a histogram sampled at 100 different points. Thus this histogram feature is actually 100 different features. I would like to reduce the dimensionality of my modeling problem by performing PCA on the histogram features, however I do not want to include the other features in the PCA in order to maintain interpretability of my model.

Ideally I would like to form a pipeline with the PCA to transform the histogram features and SVC to perform the fitting, which I would the feed to GridSearchCV to determine the SVC hyperparameters. Is it somehow possible in this setup to have PCA transform only a subset of my features (the histogram bins)? The easiest way would be to edit the PCA object to accept a feature mask, but I would certainly prefer to use existing functionality.

**EDIT**

After implementing @eickenberg's answer I realized that I also wanted an inverse_transform method for the new PCA class. This method recreates the initial feature set with columns in their original order. It is provided below for anyone else who is interested:

```
def inverse_transform(self, X):
    if self.mask is not None:
        # Inverse transform appropriate data
        inv_mask = np.arange(len(X[0])) >= sum(~self.mask)
        inv_transformed = self.pca.inverse_transform(X[:, inv_mask])

        # Place inverse transformed columns back in their original order
        inv_transformed_reorder = np.zeros([len(X), len(self.mask)])
        inv_transformed_reorder[:, self.mask] = inv_transformed
        inv_transformed_reorder[:, ~self.mask] = X[:, ~inv_mask]
        return inv_transformed_reorder
    else:
        return self.pca.inverse_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible *straight out of the box* with scikit learn. In order to be able to exploit full functionality of `Pipeline` and `GridSearchCV`, consider creating an object `MaskedPCA`, inheriting from `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` and exposing the methods `fit` and `transform`. In it you should use a `PCA` object on your masked features. The mask should be passed to the constructor.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

class MaskedPCA(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, n_components=2, mask=None):  
        # mask should contain selected cols. Suppose it is boolean to avoid code overhead
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.mask = mask

    def fit(self, X):
        self.pca = PCA(n_components=self.n_components)
        mask = self.mask
        mask = self.mask if self.mask is not None else slice(None)
        self.pca.fit(X[:, mask])
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        mask = self.mask if self.mask is not None else slice(None)
        pca_transformed = self.pca.transform(X[:, mask])
        if self.mask is not None:
            remaining_cols = X[:, ~mask]
            return np.hstack([remaining_cols, pca_transformed])
        else:
            return pca_transformed
```

You can test it on some generated data

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(100, 20)
mask = np.arange(20) > 4

mpca = MaskedPCA(n_components=2, mask=mask)

transformed = mpca.fit(X).transform(X)

# check whether first five columns are equal
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal
assert_array_equal(X[:, :5], transformed[:, :5])
```

Observe that `transformed` now has `(~mask).sum + mpca.n_components == 7` columns

Comment: Great thanks for the help, works perfectly. I also created an inverse_transform method just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Good point - I forgot about that. Would you be able to edit your `inverse_transform` into this answer?

Comment: Ok, added it in there.

Comment: Using a pipeline with the code from here would also be a possible solution: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3560

Comment: You mean using the `FunctionTransformer`? Why not!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ColumnTransformer:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html

```
pca_transformer = ColumnTransformer([('pca', PCA(), pca_columns)], remainder="passthrough")
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca_transformer', pca_transformer), ('logistic', logistic)])
```