# sk-learn pipeline with heterogeneous data: apply PCA to continous features only, after ColumnTransform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been trying to do something which  I think should be possible but cannot work it out.

At the moment I have a pipeline which looks like this:
[Pipeline diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LFga.png)

As you can see from the diagram the PCA is applied after all the ColumnsTranforms, on all tranformed features.

I would like it to apply only to the continuous features. Where it breaks down is that ColumnTransformer outputs numpy arrays and so I cannot refer back to the column names.
I tried and get the ubiquitous error `ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames`

Here is the code to create the pipeline.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import set_config
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

set_config(display="diagram")

# define the preprocessing steps. We must take care not to preprocess  features twice.
# define the ordinal encoder
ordi = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[[0,1]])
# define the OneHotEncoder
cat =OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)

preproc = ColumnTransformer([
  ('log_trans',log_scale,log_features),
  ('scaler',cont,continuous),
  ('long',long_scale,long_features),
  ('lat',lat_scale,lat_features),
  ('reg',ordi,discrete),
  ('deciles',KBin,kb_features),
  ('categ',cat,categorical)
],remainder = 'passthrough')


logreg = make_pipeline(
  preproc,
  pca_full,
  LogisticRegression(C =100,multi_class = 'multinomial',solver ='saga',max_iter = 4000,tol 
  =0.001))
logreg
```

continuous feature names are stored in the lists `continuous` , `log_features`,`long_features` and `lat_features`

There have been a few similar posts in the past but they go back some years so  I am hopeful someone might have an up to date answer. [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124622/pipeline-with-pca-on-feature-subset-only-in-scikit-learn)